# Google Drive File Iterator within Folder iterator

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am trying to write the code for a file iterator through google scripts that goes through a particular folder in my google drive, searching for files (within subfolders) of a particular name.

My current iterator only will bring up files of that name if they are in the immediate folder, not in subfolders.

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderID')
var files = folder.getFilesByName("File Name"); 
  while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
```

Is there a way to make the iterator sift through the subfolders themselves to find the files with the given name?

Comment: Already answered in [Google apps script - iterate folder and subfolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069823/google-apps-script-iterate-folder-and-subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

From a pure Comp Sci 101 perspective, you need to put that code into a function that you call recursively to descend the folder hierarchy.

However ...
don't do that. Do this ...

Fetch all of the folders in a single call and then build a memory model of the hierarchy. Use that model to create a list of candidate folder IDs, then search for your file by name, and compare the parent IDs of all matches with the list of candidate folder IDs.