# How to get FolderIterator containing only direct children of a folder in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, tree, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a script to print a list of full file paths for everything in my Google drive. The goal is to have a list like this:

```
./Docs/Doc1.gdoc
./Docs/Doc2.gdoc
./Docs/Doc3.gdoc
./Pics/2011/img1.jpg
./Pics/2011/img2.jpg
./Pics/2011/img3.jpg
...
```

It appears that this is not as simple as I thought, since Google Drive methods like `getFolders()` treat all folders as subfolders.

I tried writing something recursive to do this, until I realized the subfolders issue:

```
function getChildFolders(parent) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();    
    var pathString = childFolder.getName()
    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var fullPath = parent.getName()
      var fileName = files.next().getName()      
      fullFilePath = pathString.concat('/', fileName)
      Logger.log(fullFilePath);
    }
    // Recursive call
    getChildFolders(childFolder);
  }
}
```

I can't figure out a way to list the files in this manner in a hierarchical way. Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069823/google-apps-script-iterate-folder-and-subfolder?

Answer (score 1):

This should dump what you are looking for:

```
function dumpFilesInFolder(folder, path)
{
    path = (path || "") + "/" + folder.getName();

    Logger.log(path);

    var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
    while(subFolders.hasNext())
    {
        dumpFilesInFolder(subFolders.next(), path);
    }

    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while(files.hasNext())
    {
        Logger.log(path + "/" + files.next().getName());
    }
}

function startIt()
{
    dumpFilesInFolder(DriveApp.getRootFolder());
}
```